# Override event.preventDefault()

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery Ajax code:

```
    $("#new_form").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post("/home/new_ajax", $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
            if (data.errors == '') {
                $("#new_form").submit();
            } else {
                alert(data.errors);
            }
        }, "json");
    });
```

However, due to

```
event.preventDefault();
```

this line doesn't work:

```
 $("#new_form").submit();
```

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you tried debugging with the console? What does `data.errors` return?

Comment: No, Chrome does not report any errors. I want to prevent default action before I make form validation and once it passes, I want to submit the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) instead of `.submit()` -- it allows you to pass in extra parameters which your event handler can then utilize:

```
$("#new_form").submit(function (event, skipCustomStuff) {
    // If second parameter is truthy, let the submission happen
    if (skipCustomStuff) return;

    event.preventDefault();
    $.post("/home/new_ajax", $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
        if (data.errors == '') {
            // trigger submission passing in true as second parameter
            $("#new_form").trigger('submit', [true]);
        } else {
            alert(data.errors);
        }
    }, "json");
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But for some reason I have to press "submit" twice to make the form submitted.

Comment: @user1739770: Not sure why that happens, perhaps there's some other code that gets involved?

Comment: No, that is it. I changed it to a input type="button" to avoid preventDefault, and so I'm fine now. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to do `$("#new_form")[0].submit()`, it will bypass any jQuery bound handlers and submit the form.

```
$("#new_form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post("/home/new_ajax", $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
        if (data.errors == '') {
            $("#new_form")[0].submit();
        } else {
            alert(data.errors);
        }
    }, "json");
});
```